# How to sort results list by data id from json file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, radio-button

So everything in my naming tool works as far as displaying the names from a json file. What I can't get to work, is when the data id's tied into the choices from the radio buttons and select drop downs to filter and only display the names that have those data id's associated with them. Here is my code:

HTML for radio buttons:

```
<form class="dnt-tool" id="dnt" name="dnt">
    <div class="dnt-overlay">
        <input id="male" name="gender" type="radio" value="Male" />
        <label for="male">Male</label> 
        <input data-id="594" id="female" name="gender" type="radio" value="Female" />
        <label for="female">Female</label> 
        <input checked="checked" data-id="0" id="all" name="gender" type="radio" value="All" />
        <label for="all">All</label> 
        <select>
            <option data-id="0" value="/dog-name-finder/">Select a Category</option>
            <option data-id="0" value="/dog-name-finder/">All</option>
            <option data-id="601" value="/dog-name-finder/baby/">Baby</option>
            <option data-id="602" value="/dog-name-finder/celebrity/">Celebrity</option>
            <option data-id="603" value="/dog-name-finder/cute/">Cute</option>
            <option data-id="598" value="/dog-name-finder/disney/">Disney</option>
            <option data-id="600" value="/dog-name-finder/fancy/">Fancy</option>
            <option data-id="605" value="/dog-name-finder/most-popular/">Most Popular</option>
            <option data-id="599" value="/dog-name-finder/presidential/">Presidential</option>
            <option data-id="597" value="/dog-name-finder/techy/">Techy</option>
            <option data-id="596" value="/dog-name-finder/television/">Television</option>
            <option data-id="606" value="/dog-name-finder/trendy/">Trendy</option>
            <option data-id="595" value="/dog-name-finder/unisex/">Unisex</option>
            <option data-id="604" value="/dog-name-finder/video-game/">Video Game</option> 
        </select>
    </div><!-- end of dnt-overlay -->
    <div class="dnt-btn">
        <button id="submit" type="submit">Show Names</button>
    </div><!-- end of dnt btn -->
</form><!-- end of dnt-tool -->
```

Here is the jquery that displays results in a popup(the pop up works fine):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#dnt').submit(function(e){
            var cat_id = $('.dnt-overlay > select > option:selected').data('id') || 0;
            var cat_title = $('.dnt-overlay > select > option:selected').text() || 'All';
            if (cat_id === 0)
            {
                cat_title = 'All';
            }
            var dnt_url = $('.dnt-overlay > select > option:selected').val() || '/dog-name-finder/';
            var gender = $('.dnt-overlay > [name=gender]:checked').data('id') || 0;
            var gender_title = $('.dnt-overlay > [name=gender]:checked').val() || 'All';
            var title = cat_title;
            var html = '';

            var params = '';

            if(window.innerWidth <= 320)
            {
                params = '?limit=18';
            }
            else
            {
                params = '?limit=21';
            }


            if (cat_id > 0)
            {
                params += '&' + 'cat_id=' + cat_id;
            }

            if (gender > 0 && cat_title != 'Gender Agnostic' && cat_title != 'Unisex' && cat_title != 'Male' && cat_title != 'Female')
            {
                title += ' ' + gender_title;
                params += '&' + 'gender=' + gender;
                if(cat_title == 'All')
                {
                    dnt_url += gender_title.toLowerCase() + '/';
                }
                else
                {
                    dnt_url += '?gender=' + gender_title.charAt(0).toLowerCase();
                }
            }
            title += ' Dog Names';

            $('#dnt-popup > h1').text(title);       

            e.preventDefault(); // We don't need to send the form, because it's all local
            if($('#male').is(':checked')) { // Check if male is checked
                $('#dnt-popup').removeClass('dnt-all').removeClass('dnt-female').addClass('dnt-male');
            } 
            else if($('#female').is(':checked')) { // Check if female is checked 
                $('#dnt-popup').removeClass('dnt-all').removeClass('dnt-male').addClass('dnt-female');
            } 
            else if($('#all').is(':checked')) { // Check if all is checked
                $('#dnt-popup').removeClass('dnt-female').removeClass('dnt-male').addClass('dnt-all');
            }
            $.ajax({
               type : 'GET',
               dataType: "json",
              url: "dnt.json" + params,
            })

            .done(function( data ) {

                $.each(data, function( index, value ) {
                    if(index == 21){
                        return false;
                    }

                    html +='<li>' + value.Name + '</li>';
                });

                $('#dnt-popup > .results-list > ul').html(html);

                $.magnificPopup.open({ // open pop up for male
                    items: {
                        src: '#dnt-popup',
                        type: 'inline'

                    },//item
                        mainClass: 'animated slideInRight'
                });///popup open
            }); 
         });///submit function
       });///submit function 
    </script>
```

This is some of the data from my json file:

```
       [
          {
             "Name":"Aaliyah",
             "Female":594,
             "Baby":601
           },
           {
              "Name":"Abby",
              "Female":594
            },
            {
               "Name":"Abe",
               "Male":593,
               "Video Games":604
            },
            {
               "Name":"Abigail",
               "Female":594,
               "Baby":601
            },
            {
               "Name":"Abu",
               "Male":593,
               "Disney":598
            },
            {
               "Name":"Ace",
               "Male":593,
               "Fancy":600,
               "Cool":611
             }
         ]
```

Is there something I'm missing here? Please help.

Comment: Please remove all code not relevant to the specific problem as per [mcve]. Then add an explanation of what this code is specifically supposed to do and what it is or isn't currently doing and any errors that it might be producing as per [ask]

Comment: ALL relevant code is there @charlietfl

Comment: There is lots of code NOT relevant such as plugin code, ajax etc

Comment: the ajax is used to parse the names from the json file @charlietfl

Comment: Still not entirely clear what it is you are trying to do or what the specific problem is or what we should be looking at

Comment: @charlietfl display the names from the json file. What I can't get to work, is when the data ID's tied into the choices from the radio buttons and select tag dropdowns to filter and only display the names that have those data ID's associated with them.

Comment: Create an array of all the form values ... use `Array#filter()` on your data checking if each item is in the forms values array. The create html from the filtered array.  More common approach would be submit all the form values to server and only return what is applicable

Comment: How would I do that being, the json is in a separate file? @charlietfl

Comment: First loop through the form controls to make one array....then loop through the ajax data and compare